# C++ reference deleted function error

Tags: c++

```
void User::addAccount(const Account& _account) { this->account = _account; }
```

is giving me an error, where as

`void User::addDevice(const Device& _device){ this->device = _device; }`

does not give error. error is

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2280   'Account &Account::operator =(const Account &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

I have used the same construct and now is an error

Comment: `std::is_same<Account, Device>::value` is `false`. But more importantly: `std::is_copy_assignable<Account>::value` is `false`, too.

Comment: it's just a simple setter. The device setter works as does many others, but now visual studio is giving this error. it's written in same fashion

Comment: ^ It depends on the type. You know, there are types that cannot be copy-assigned, maybe only move-assigned or not even that.

Comment: it had a const variable in wrong place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overload = operator to be able to do this.

- See, when you type x = y in any code and if both are of the same type and compiler(provided you are not using interpreted language) knows how to assign them then this will work fine.
- Now Account is your custom type, so you have to tell c++ compiler how to assign them.

Device class/structure will have overloaded it.
This is a quite simple example for the same check this out

[Link to tutorialpoint = operator overloading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/assignment_operators_overloading.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. a stray const variable hiding